# need to Iterate through the cells in the array, and set the value of each cell to be the product of its coordinates

Tags: java

need to Iterate through the cells in the array, and set the value of each cell to be the product of its coordinates (the cell at position 0,0 would have value 0, the cell at position 2,4 would have value 8, etc.). honestly im just really stuck and need some help getting started

Comment: also needs to be a 2d array and it needs to call the array from another method

Comment: *"Call the array from another method"*? How big is your 2D-array?

Comment: i need to be able to send a 2 d array to it there is no array given or plainly stated. exact question: Define a method called TwoDimProcess which takes a 2 dimensional array of integer as a parameter. The function does not return anything. The function will Iterate through the cells in the array, and set the value of each cell to be the product of its coordinates (the cell at position 0,0 would have value 0, the cell at position 2,4 would have value 8, etc.).

Comment: Please post any code you have attempted so we could look at it and provide you feedback on where you might have a misconception. Do note that while StackOverflow is a great resource for beginning programmers, it is not a place to find people to help you write your apps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
void twoDimProcess(int[][] matrix) {
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = i*j;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to print the 2D-array, I'd do it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("[ ");
    for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("]"); //new line
}
```

Comment: im am getting an error when i go to display the results what would be the best way to print so i can see if this works? (if i seem like a noob its because i am lol)